# How to activate all the parent(i.e. one tab) of a UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

For an error validation mechanism, I've to be able to "navigate" in my application to one specific pane.

Currently I've one "SelectedNode" and tries to focus the control that is bound to this property(basically, I've an AttachedProperty to set the IsFocus, based on the name).

My issue is that sometimes this page contains tabs. And it appears that the control cannot be focused if it's hidden(not in the active tab).

Is there a way from an UserControl to go up in its visual tree to "activate" all his parent?

I cannot just bind the "SelectedIndex" of my tabcontrol in the viewModel, for a lot of reasons:

1. The UserControl that has the tab has one sub user control for each tab, so the usercontrol doesn't know what is in which usercontrol
2. Putting such things in the ViewModel is wrong, the ViewModel should not have to know that it's displayed in tabs or all in the same pane

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could use some kind of attached behavior, which will (on "IsActive" changed event) go up on visual tree and activate each parent element?

Comment: If you know how to "activate each parent element", I definitely have the structure for the rest

Comment: There is a `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent()` method. Take a look [here](http://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/02/finding_ancestor_elements_in_w/)

Comment: @vasily.sib Ok, and how do you "activate"?

Comment: some kind of `foreach (var parent in GetParents(AssociatedObject)) { if (parent is TabItem tabItem) tabItem.IsSelected = true; }`

Comment: @vasily.sib Okay, that would mean that I've to know each kind of activable element. I was wondering if there was an `Activate`-like method on all `FrameworkElement`

Comment: I think there is no `Activate`-like method for all kinds of `FrameworkElement`. I think this is because not all kinds of of `FrameworkElement` may be "activated". For example, "activating" a `DockPanel` or `TextBlock` is meaningless. Do you have examples of another controls, that need to be "activated" to show its content?